# extracting a tuple from a bag

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I have a relation of bags of tuples which looks like this.  The tuples in the bag come preordered.

`{(123,1383313457523,1,US),(123,1383313457543,2,US),(123,1383313457553,3,US)}`
`{(456,1383313457623,1,UK),(456,1383313457643,2,UK),(456,1383313457653,3,UK)}`
`{(789,1383313457723,1,UK),(789,1383313457743,2,UK),(789,1383313457753,3,UK)}`

Where the tuple is: `(id:chararray,time:long,event:chararray,location,chararray)`

I want to get the first element of each bag.  So my expected output would be:

`(123,1383313457523,1,US)
(456,1383313457623,1,UK)
(789,1383313457723,1,UK)`

I tried this:

```
data = load 'mydata.txt' USING  PigStorage('\t');
A = FOREACH data GENERATE $0;

dump A;
```

Which produces the same list of data bags as I had originally.

Alternatively trying to extract just the ids

```
data = load 'mydata.txt' USING  PigStorage('\t');
A = FOREACH data GENERATE $0.$0;

dump A;
```

I expect:

`(123)
(456)
(789)`

but I get

`{(123),(123),(123)}
{(456),(456),(456)}
{(789),(789),(789)}`

How do I adjust my script to get the data that I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LIMIT` inside a nested foreach:

```
A = FOREACH data { first = LIMIT $0 1; GENERATE FLATTEN(first); }
```

You cannot count on the tuples in your bag being ordered, since by definition a bag is unordered. However, you can also put an `ORDER BY` in a nested foreach:

```
A = FOREACH data { ord = ORDER $0 BY $1; first = LIMIT ord 1; GENERATE FLATTEN(first); }
```

I find these to be more readable if they are split up onto multiple lines:

```
A =
    FOREACH data {
        ord = ORDER $0 BY $1;
        first = LIMIT ord 1;
    GENERATE
        FLATTEN(first);
    };
```

I'm assuming that the bag is ordered by the second field of each tuple (`$1`).